# Magento 1.9 / OpenMage: sales_flat_quote / sales/quote model fields "is_changed" and "converted_at"

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1, openmage

There are two fields in the `sales_flat_quote` table which appear to do exactly... nothing.

We are building a quote system for our client that uses Magento 1.9, now moved to OpenMage / Magento 1 LTS and want to use as much existing functionality as possible. For example, it makes sense to use the existing `sales_flat_quote` table as it already has an `is_active` switch making it easy to move quotes to and from the customer's cart.

### *`is_changed`*

This `is_changed` seems to be completely unused. However, it's set to `1` on every save via the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_beforeSave()`:

```php
if (!$this->hasChangedFlag() || $this->getChangedFlag() == true) {
    $this->setIsChanged(1);
} else {
    $this->setIsChanged(0);
}
```

This logic sets `is_changed` to `1` because `...ChangedFlag` is never set anywhere in the [OpenMage / Magento 1 LTS code](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts).

***Side note:*** Even after the code was migrated to 2.x, the 2.x [developer exam notes](https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes/blob/master/8.%20Customizing%20the%20Checkout%20Process/1.%20Demonstrate%20ability%20to%20use%20quote%2C%20quote%20item%2C%20address%2C%20and%20shopping%20cart%20rules%20in%20checkout.md) state this field is not used. I can't find the equivalent code in 2.x (unless I'm looking in the wrong place); so presumably it really is not used in 2.x.

I also looked into whether there was any link between the methods `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::hasChangedFlag()`, `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getChangedFlag()` and `Varien_Object::hasDataChanges()` because theoretically, these would have been the same sort of indicator, had `is_changed` even been used.

I think it's safe to say that this field should just not be used. If the original idea was to use it as some type of event indicator, it seems that it was never implemented.

### *`converted_at`*

The `converted_at` field seems to be logical in that it should represent when a quote was converted to an order. However, this is also always NULL (it's default DB value) indicating it's never set; and there does not appear to be anywhere in the code where it's set.

*`is_active`*

Note: `is_active` defaults in the DB to `1` and therefore Magento has to modify it calling `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::setIsActive(false)` when needing it to be `is_active=0`.

`is_active` is the flag that Magento uses to determine whether this is the active shopping cart. In `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::getQuote()`, this method creates a new

In order to qualify, it must have `is_active=1` and the `store_id` must also match.

**Caveat:** In `Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer::setLoadPersistentQuote()`, `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::setLoadInactive()` is called making `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::getQuote()` load an inactive cart because persistent carts are shared across stores. I think?

### How To Find A Completed Quote/Cart?

When a quote/cart is completed, the `is_active` value is set to `0` but that does not mean it was actually converted into an order. This is because when using the admin panel to create an order, the `sales/quote` object is also used in the `adminhtml/session` object whilst the order is being made.

`sales/quote`'s created in the admin panel are always `is_active=0`. This is because if they were set to `is_active=1` the frontend would pick it up as an active cart.

But you can't just switch a quote/cart from `is_active=0` to `is_active=1` because there might already be a `is_active=1` in the customer's active session. For this, there is a method called `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::merge(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote)` that allows you to merge in another quote which is useful (and used) for moving admin orders to the customer's active cart in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create::moveQuoteItem()`.

**Note:** `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer::cleanExpiredQuotes()` deletes all quotes where the `is_active` value is `0` and `updated_at` is before the **System > Config > Checkout > Cart > Quote Lifetime (days)** (`$lifetime *= 86400`) date/time. This means that `is_active = 1` quote records are never deleted and the cart will live forever.

It seems the only way to find whether a quote/cart is completed to an order is to INNER JOIN the order table `sales_flat_order.quote_id = sales_flat_quote.entity_id` and test for the `sales_flat_quote.entity_id` field being `NOT NULL` if an order was created.

Further reading from a [similar thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99224/role-of-is-active-in-sales-flat-quote).

Comment: Have you looked into the column `reserved_order_id` in the quote table?

Comment: @kiatng yes we did look at that. But that could technically be set and order not placed in the event of a runtime exception. So it's not all that reliable. We need a sort of after-save event flag/indicator that is definitive.